# How to find out Subversion repository version?

Tags: svn, berkeley-db, fsfs

How can I determine current version of my repository to see if I need to upgrade it (svnadmin upgrade)?

In reality I'm hosting SVN with 3rd party and I want to find out if I need to ask them to upgrade my repos or not.

I'm asking since 1.5 server will keep repo version at 1.4, unless I miss something?

Answer (score 46):

Have a look at `<REPO>/db/format`. After upgrading to 1.5 format, my `format` file shows:

```
3
layout sharded 1000
```

Before it used to be:

```
2
```

Comment: It's '4' for Subversion 1.6. This is /probably/ the best way to determine the version of the repository.

Comment: where is this information? I'm on windows and using tortoisesvn.

Comment: -1. The questioner has stated that the repo is on a third party SVN host.  They don't give you access to the physical repository.  There is no way for the questioner to directly access this file.  BTW, no argument this is the best way to determine the version if you have access to it.

Comment: I have my  repo url , and see branches , tags, truck folder but don't see any db or format folder? Where I can find this Db or db/format folder? I don't have access to higher levels of repo directory structure?

Comment: @supernova, you need to go to the file system it self where svn stores all it's files. Not view the svn contents through a svn client.

Answer (score 27):

Take the `http` or `https` link to your repository and cut & paste it into a browser.  The Subversion <strike>repository</strike> ***server*** version appears in the footer by default.

> Powered by Subversion version 1.4.5 (r25188).

One would assume that a `1.4` server won't be running against a `1.5` repository.

For details, see the [Subversion 1.5 Release Notes](http://subversion.tigris.org/svn_1.5_releasenotes.html)

Thanks to @Omus for the correction.

Comment: I thought this was SVN server software version, not repository version?

Comment: but it could run the other way around, no?

Comment: That's where the "one would assume" comes in - possible, but doesn't make much sense, does it?

Comment: "The Subversion 1.5 server works with 1.4 and older repositories, and it will not upgrade such repositories to 1.5 unless specifically requested to via the svnadmin upgrade command." - http://subversion.tigris.org/svn_1.5_releasenotes.html#repos-upgrades So you shouldn't assume :)

Comment: This doesn't work for VisualSVN server - it doesn't seem to provide the version number.

Answer (score 6):

You can check the content of the file "format" under the "db" directory. If it shows 3 then it has been upgraded to 1.5 (that's the version of the updated fielsystem). If it is 2 then it is 1.4 or older.

Answer (score 5):

There is a difference between Subversion Repository Version / Schema (1), and Subversion Repository FSFS Version (2).

FSFS, in contrast to Berkeley DB, or the developmental FSX, is a backend data storage method. [FSFS](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.reposadmin.basics.backends) is "a versioned filesystem implementation that uses the native OS filesystem directly".

(1):  The Subversion repository version / schema is found in the [REPO]/format file.  The current versions from the Subversion [repos_upgrade_HOWTO](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/notes/repos_upgrade_HOWTO) document are:

```
SUBVERSION VERSION NUMBER           SCHEMA VERSION
-------------------------           --------------
Up to and including 0.27            1
0.28 - 0.33.1                       2
0.34 - 1.3                          3
(no released version used this)     4
1.4 -                               5
```

(2):  The repository FSFS format however, is found in the [REPO]/db/format file.  The current versions are in the [libsvn_fs_fs FSFS Structure](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/subversion/libsvn_fs_fs/structure) document, in the *Filesystem formats* section.  They currently are:

```
Format 1, understood by Subversion 1.1+
Format 2, understood by Subversion 1.4+
Format 3, understood by Subversion 1.5+
Format 4, understood by Subversion 1.6+
Format 5, understood by Subversion 1.7-dev, never released
Format 6, understood by Subversion 1.8
Format 7, understood by Subversion 1.9
Format 8, understood by Subversion 1.10+
```

Also, as of Subversion 1.9 you can now use the *svnadmin info* command to gain both the Subversion Repository Version / Schema, as well as the Subversion Repository FSFS Version (See:  [Subversion 1.9 Release Notes - FSFS Improvements](https://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.9.html#fsfs-improvements) as well as [Subversion 1.9 Release Notes - svnadmin Changes and Improvements](https://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.9.html#svnadmin-info))

Answer (score 4):

For VisualSVN Server, even it uses custom pages, you can still view the page source:)

Comment: I was able to determine the version of the repository I need to use with this answer. Well thought!

Answer (score 1):

I would also suggest spoofing response headers because some server installations ([VisualSVN Server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/) comes to mind) uses custom pages which unfortunately doesn't show Subversion server version.

You could use [Fiddler2](http://www.fiddlertool.com/fiddler/) to spoof request/response to the server. If You're using an HTTPS connection be sure to check "Decrypt HTTPS traffic" option in: 
Tools->Fiddler Options->HTTPS

Answer (score 0):

If you use VisualSVN Server you can find out the format of the repository via the VisualSVN Server Manager console or via PowerShell. Read the article [KB135: Understanding the Subversion repository types and formats](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00135/) for more information.

### VisualSVN Server Manager

Follow these steps to find out the format of a repository:

1. Start the **VisualSVN Server Manager** console.
2. Right-click a repository and click **Properties**.
3. Click the **Details** tab.

[image]

## PowerShell

Follow these steps to find out the format of a repository via PowerShell:

1. [Start the PowerShell console](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00165/).
2. Execute the following command:
   `Get-SvnRepository MyRepo | Format-List`

[image]

Answer (score -2):

I think what you want is "svnlook youngest"

Comment: it also looks for the file "format", which is not found at my repo.

Comment: svnlook youngest only show the latest revision number in the repo. Not the version of the repo database.