# Obtain SubVersion 1.4 executables for Windows

Tags: svn, svnadmin, fsfs

I need to work with an old repository, whose db/format contains

```
2
```

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282460/how-to-find-out-subversion-repository-version), I understand that this means it's version 1.4.

I have only 1.5 executables, which produce a db/format containing

```
3
layout sharded 1000
```

I've tried to use the 1.5 `svnadmin` to verify the 1.4 repo, but it fails with

```
'vnadmin: Unknown FS type 'fsfs
```

If anyone's got any ideas on how to fix this, that'd be great. My current working plan is to obtain 1.4 executables.

The problem I have is that I've done a fair amount of searching, and I can't find any SubVersion 1.4 executable downloads.

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try http://subversion.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectDocumentList?folderID=469&expandFolder=469&folderID=8100

tons of old releases in there

Comment: Thanks! Don't know how I couldn't find that, although I spent 20 mins looking.

I d/l'd and installed. Unfortunately, I still get the same error: 'vnadmin: Unknown FS type 'fsfs

If no-one else can advise on that. I'll make this the accepted answer.

Comment: You might look at http://www.opensubscriber.com/message/users@subversion.tigris.org/8608506.html for that message.  It can imply a corrupt backup.