# How can I find the version number for my SVN server software, using TortoiseSVN?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm using TortoiseSVN 1.6.8, and suspect I may be having a version incompatibility with my server.

How can I discover the version of SVN running on the server?

Preferably from Tortoise, but failing that, from the SVN command line.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Assuming that your SVN repository is getting accessed as an HTTP URL, say http://www.server.com/mysvnrepos/, you should be able to access the URL from your web browser.

From Windows Explorer, try File -> TortoiseSVN -> Repo Browser. Copy the URL of the repository and paste into your browser. It may return a source revision list, along with a footer at the bottom of the web page that reads "Powered by Subversion x.x.x."

Comment: For VisualServerSVN, view in browser as suggested, then right click and view the HTML source. You will see xml, the root element includes the version as an attribute e.g. `<svn version="1.8.8 (r1568071)">`

Comment: "It may", but it may not. In my case, this work with old server versions. With the recent ones, there's no such message.

Answer (score 0):

See [How to find my Subversion server version number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141146/how-to-find-my-subversion-server-version-number)

Comment: Thanks for the link - don't know why I missed it when I searched.  Highest voted answer is the same as Shan's, but Shan's explanation is better, IMO.