# How to find SVN version?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm on a Windows machine.  When I type in `svn --version`, I get this:

```
'svn' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I'm using TortoiseSVN.  Is there some way to view the version through it?

I have looked at this but the server does not output any version information: [How to find my Subversion server version number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141146/how-to-find-my-subversion-server-version-number)

Comment: IIRC Tortoise doesn't come with a command line client, but works with an embedded svn library (or something like that). I usually work with [SlikSVN](https://sliksvn.com/) when I need a command line client.I don't know of any way to know the server SVN version without accessing the server.

Comment: Right-click, choose Tortoise SVN->About from the context menu, see Version Information. It gives you both the Tortoise SVN and SVN version numbers.

Comment: @watery: It comes with a command-line version as well.

Comment: @KenWhite Where's it? Or is it a separate download / install option?

Comment: @watery: It's in the TortoiseSVN\bin folder (svn.exe, svnadmin.exe, svnlook.exe, etc.)

Comment: @KenWhite Just to clear that out (nothing to do with the question) this is my \bin .exe list: {ConnectVPN.exe, SubWCRev.exe, SubWCRevCOM.exe, TortoiseBlame.exe, TortoiseIDiff.exe, TortoiseMerge.exe, TortoisePlink.exe, TortoiseProc.exe, TortoiseUDiff.exe, TSVNCache.exe}

Comment: @watery: I have considerably more than that, and did nothing except download and install TortoiseSVN (64-bit) on Windows 7.

Comment: 4thSpace, just to be sure, you're not looking to the svn repository format version, right?

Comment: ... yes there is a separate option in the setup menu of TortoiseSVN to install command-line SVN tools https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2967176/where-is-svn-exe-in-my-machine#2967196

Answer (score 12):

If you have TortoiseSVN integrated with Windows File Explorer, then you can follow these steps:

1. Right-click on the desktop or in the File Explorer.
2. Click **TortoiseSVN**.
3. Click **About**. Versions of the components used by TortoiseSVN are listed there.

[image]

Comment: Just to clarify, "Subversion 1.13.0" in the above screen shot is not the Subversion Server version number.  That is the client SVN version number.   You can prove this by upgrading to latest version of TortoiseSVN on your workstation and without upgrading the SVN Server version you will notice the Tortoise About dialog box will show the "Subversion" release being incremented, even though you didn't upgrade the server.  In short, the TortoiseSVN About dialog box does not show the actual SVN Server release version #.

Comment: @B_e_n_n_y_ I was assuming that the question is only about the version of the client. If this question is about the version of the server, there is another thread https://stackoverflow.com/q/141146/761095

Answer (score 0):

The error means that the `svn.exe` client is either missing on your computer or its parent path is not included in the [**%PATH%** environment variable](https://superuser.com/q/284342/146834).

- See this thread when you want to find out your SVN server version: [How to find my Subversion server version number?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/141146/761095)
- See [this question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1625406/761095) when you use TortoiseSVN on client side to find out the version of the client.
- When you have this problem on a computer with VisualSVN Server, see this article - [KB13: Using Subversion command-line tools with VisualSVN Server](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00013/).