# How to Tell Which Version of the Subversion Server Using Tigris Subclipse within Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse, tigris

I'm reading the Subversion book "Version Control with Subversion For Subversion 1.7."  There are several sections in the book which state that *this* or *that* only works with version 1.x or greater of Subversion.  So, this raises the question "how do I know the version number of the Subversion server to which my Eclipse client is connecting?"

Now, I happen to have remote Subversion repositories hosted by Beanstalkapp.com, so I suppose I can go to their site and ask them, but is there a way to tell from within Eclipse to which version of Subversion my Eclipse client is connecting?

I'm using the Tigris plugin for Eclipse to access the remote Subversion server (at Beanstalkapp.com).  The version of Eclipse is Kepler SR 2.

(Just a note to differentiate this question from this similar question: [How to find my Subversion server version number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141146/how-to-find-my-subversion-server-version-number).  I'm not looking for some CURL command or other command line initiated command to determine the Subversion server version number.  I'd like to be able to do this from within Eclipse, hopefully without having to add any plugins other than the standard Subversion plugins -- Tigris in my case).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find my Subversion server version number?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141146/how-to-find-my-subversion-server-version-number)

Answer (score 1):

It is bad practice for server software to advertise its version number.  If you browse a Subversion http repository directly, it will sometimes show the version number in the footer, but this is something admins can and should turn off.

A Subversion client does not know the version of the server it is talking to.  All 1.x clients and 1.y server versions are compatible with each other.  The server and client simply negotiate their capabilities with each other.  So you can sometimes get a rough idea of a server version by knowing its capabilities.

In general, there is no need for you to know the version of the server.  The client will work out those details and generally only minor low level feature details even care about this.  For example, the only functional difference between a 1.7 and 1.8 server are some low-level HTTP protocol differences that can be leveraged. These do not manifest as user-visible features.

The Subversion release notes typically have a table that says which features need the client or server.  The majority of new features only need a new client.  The ones that need a new server usually have to do with server-specific features related to how it stores data on disk, which the client does not need to know.

See [Subversion Release Notes](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/)