# How to get CollabNet Subversion Repository server version

Tags: svn, server, version, collabnet

I need to know the version of our source code server. Which is a collabnet server. I tried [svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/tools/client-side/server-version.py](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/tools/client-side/server-version.py) but I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:661)
```

Then I added the following:

```
import ssl

try:
     _create_unverified_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
except AttributeError:
     pass
else:
     ssl._create_default_https_context = _create_unverified_https_context
```

But then I get the following:

```
ERROR: bad status response: 400 Date: Wed, 22 Feb 2017 14:53:12 GMT
Server: Apache
Content-Length: 347
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

I am working on windows. I already came across [How to find my Subversion server version number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141146/how-to-find-my-subversion-server-version-number) but none of the answers are for collabnet repository, which e.g. doesn't return the version on a web browser. There is a comment in one of the answers: "CollabNet also does not display a version number - either visibly or in the source of the page.", but not specifying how to do it in that case.

Comment: Why don't you ask the admin? You could easily check this on the server.

Comment: I want to have an automatic script logging this for future reference, it can change over time, can't ask admin for this!