# HPUX Subversion client no longer connects to remote repository

Tags: svn

I use (and have used for many years) the Subversion (revision control) 'svn' client on a set of HPUX 11.31 Itanium I2 servers.
Recently, after some routine security patches applied by IT, my svn client apparently stopped being able to connect to the remote repository (-u option).  There is no option to revert from any of the patches.

Example:  When I run the 'svn status -u' command I now get the following error:

$ svn status -u

/usr/lib/hpux32/dld.so: Unsatisfied code symbol 'SSL_load_error_strings' in load module '/usr/local/lib/hpux32/libneon.so'.
Killed

Anyone got any ideas on how to fix this problem?

My svn version is:

$ svn --version

svn, version 1.7.8 (r1419691)
compiled Jan 25 2013, 13:14:55

Comment: Can you also update the svn server version? Refer to the answer here to get the server svn version https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141146/how-to-find-my-subversion-server-version-number/9502906#9502906