# Upgrade SVN Client (w/Tortoise) from 1.7.2 to 1.14.1. Play nice with existing SVN server?

Tags: svn, client, tortoisesvn, upgrade

If an SVN Client (w/Tortoise) is upgraded from 1.7.2 to 1.14.1...
will it play nice with and existing SVR server that is presumably of the
same "era" as the client?

Have TortoiseSVN on top of SVN client 1.7.2.

Collabnet SVN server of indeterminate age.

Will the upgraded SVN client (v1.14.1) interact well with the TBD-age SVN server?

On a side note, how to determine the version of the Collabnet server?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> On a side note, how to determine the version of the Collabnet server?

You should see the version in the server's admin console or README.txt and other files on the server computer.

See also [How to find my Subversion server version number?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/141146/761095)

> Will the upgraded SVN client (v1.14.1) interact well with the TBD-age SVN server?

[Subversion 1.14 Release Notes | Compatibility Concerns](https://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.14.html#compatibility):

Older clients and servers interoperate transparently with 1.14 servers and clients. However, some of the new 1.14 features may not be available unless both client and server are the latest version. There are also cases where a new feature will work but will run less efficiently if the client is new and the server old.